# ImportError: No module named array_import -----scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am facing problem with importing io module in scipy
and python shell shows an error as following.

```
import scipy.io.array_import

ImportError: No module named array_import
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

By reading some post on net I also tried using

```
import numpy.loadtxt
```

but that too doesnt work

ImportError: No module named loadtxt

Comment: `loadtxt` isn't a module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.loadtxt` is a function, not a module. That's why you can't import `loadtxt`:

```
In [33]: import numpy
In [34]: numpy.loadtxt
Out[34]: <function loadtxt at 0x9f8bca4>
```

Comment: or `from numpy import loadtxt`

Answer (score 1):

See [this message](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-August/026325.html) on the SciPy user mailing list:

> > I am facing problem with importing `io` module in `scipy`
> >     and python shell shows an error as following.
> >
> > ```
> > import scipy.io.array_import
> > ImportError: No module named array_import
> > ```
>
> `array_import` was removed in Scipy 0.8. If you are looking for
>   read_array  and write_array, you should use `numpy.savetxt` and
>   `numpy.loadtxt` instead.