# ImportError: No module named array_import

Tags: python, scipy

Anyone know how to solve this error?

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: No module named array_import

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930314/importerror-no-module-named-array-import-scipy

Comment: Please clarify the following: exactly what you are asking, what code causes this problem, what circumstances it happens under.

Comment: Please go back to www.diveintopython.net and spend some times.

Answer (score 0):

`Note: It's Stack Overflow etiquette to post the code that caused the problem.`

Your problem is most likely caused by importing "too far" into a set of modules (all the way to an actual member instead of a module or submodule):

```
import module_name.sub_module.array_import
```

rather than either

1. `from module_name.sub_module import array_import`
2. `import module_name.sub_module`

but without code it's impossible to tell.

**EDIT**

@Dave, makes a great point that you also might be missing the module entirely.  Try a different version or better yet use whatever the library you're attempting to use replaced the old version with.

Comment: Based on the question linked to in @aix's comment, it is also plausible that the asker was trying to import array_import from scipy, where it had been removed. Again, without code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: True, sadly my `telepathy_module`'s import also threw `ImportError`